# Programmatically updating answer for an unanswered question in Custom Question Answering

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I have created a custom question answering project using Microsoft Conginitive Services and deployed the same.
Now I would like to create an UI where an user can see the unanswered questions and update the knowledge base with appropriate answer using the UI itself.

From the deployment details, I am able to extract the Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key. But I am little confused about the appropriate way of API call in my UI to track and update the unanswered questions.

Could not find many write-up or examples regarding this. Please guide me regarding the same.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the questions answering resource type you are using, as this service has evolved.

### Azure Cognitive Service for Language (end of 2021)

This is the newest version of QnA Maker (as of late 2021), now called "Custom question answering" being part of Azure Cognitive Services for Language.

This service has a better offering in terms of API:

- Service documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cognitive-services/language-service/?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365)
- API documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/cognitiveservices/questionanswering/question-answering-projects?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365)

The "active learning" feature is offered through Language Studio portal (see [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/language-service/question-answering/tutorials/active-learning?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365)).

But if you want something custom, you might be interested in the [Authoring API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/language-service/question-answering/how-to/authoring?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365): programmatically, you could use "Get QnAs" operation will give you all QnAs, and the `RetrieveQnaRecord` [object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/questionanswering/question-answering-projects/get-qnas?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365#retrieveqnarecord) included in the response contains a `SuggestedQuestionsCluster` [object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/questionanswering/question-answering-projects/get-qnas?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365#suggestedquestionscluster) which could lead to interesting feedbacks to add.

### QnA Maker (v4.0)

QnA Maker 4.0 has a REST API documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/cognitiveservices-qnamaker/?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365).

In addition, you can directly check some calls using the API exposition in the right region. Example for West US [here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5a93fcf85b4ccd136866eb37/operations/5ac266295b4ccd1554da75ff?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365)

=> For this service, there is no "feedback" solution exposed. The API allows to update a knowledge base, but you will not have an operation providing unanswered questions.